# Delayed submit results in multiple continuous submits

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms

I have the following jQuery code, the point of this code is to create a short time delay, so the AJAX request gets time to execute properly:

```
$('#form_id').submit(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    $submit_url = $(this).data('submitUrl');
    $submit_url = $submit_url.replace('http://','').replace(window.location.host,'');

    if ($(this).data('toBeAjaxSubmitted') == true) {
        $.ajax($submit_url, {
            type : $(this).attr('method'),
            data : $(this).serialize(),
            complete : function(data) {
                $(this).data('toBeAjaxSubmitted', false);
                $('#form_id').submit();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

What happens is, the form starts off with a submit url that I need to submit to in order for the component to save an entry to the database. But I also need user input to submit directly to a payment gateway URL where the user then makes a payment.

The code above creates the AJAX request, but does not return to normal postback behaviour (via `$('#form_id').submit()`).

It keeps submitting the form over and over, but never posts to the gateway URL or redirects out.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks matt b. The `java` tag was an accident I think.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me after some more debugging:

```
$('#chronoform_Online_Submission_Step8_Payment').submit(function(e) {
    var form = this;
    e.preventDefault();
    $submit_url = $(this).data('submitUrl');
    $submit_url = $submit_url.replace('http://','').replace(window.location.host,'');

    if ($(this).data('toBeAjaxSubmitted') == true) {
        $.ajax($submit_url, {
            type : $(this).attr('method'),
            data : $(this).serialize(),
            complete : function(data, status) {

            }
        }).done(function() {
            form.submit();
        });
    }
});
```

What really put me on the wrong path was that in Chrome's Developer Tools I had the following option enabled **'Disable cache (while DevTools is open)'** and this was causing some headaches with inconsistent behaviour between Safari, Firefox (which worked) and Chrome which did not.

Comment: To be clear, the change is using `this.submit()` vs `$(this).submit()`. `this.submit()` submits the form without triggering the submit event, thus avoiding an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

What about some **[fiddling](http://jsfiddle.net/3SGXu/)** with this approach?

```
$('#form_id').submit(function(e) {

    // closures
    var $form = $(this);
    var fAjaxComplete = function(data) {
        // don't send the ajax again
        $form.data('toBeAjaxSubmitted', 'false');

        // maybe do some form manipulation with data...

        // re-trigger submit
        $form.trigger('submit');
    };
    var oAjaxObject = {
        type : $form.attr('method'),
        data : $form.serialize(),
        complete : fAjaxComplete
    };

    var sSubmitUrl = $form.data('submitUrl');
    // scrub url
    sSubmitUrl = sSubmitUrl.replace('http://','').replace(window.location.host,'');

    // if ajax needed
    if ($form.data('toBeAjaxSubmitted') != 'false') {
        // go get ajax
        $.ajax(sSubmitUrl, oAjaxObject);
        // don't submit, prevent native submit behavior, we are using ajax first!
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }

    // if you got here, go ahead and submit
    return true;

});
```